# Trying to implement a stack and the bracket matching problem but cannot figure out some semantic errors

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, stack

I am required to write my own stack using an array which then I have to implement the bracket matching problem.

This is my algorithm: if we're given the string: "(())" it is returning "not balanced" when it should say it is "balanced". If you look over at BracketCheck.java near the end it tests whether the stack is empty where if it is it should return true and say the given string: "(())" is balanced.  I am having problems debugging it and the result of the operation is incorrect.

Here is my stack and main class code:

```java
public class Stack {
        // instance fields:
        private char array[]; // our array
        private int topOfStack; // this indicates the value for each position

        // overloaded constructor:
        public Stack(int size) {
            this.array = new char[size]; // here we instantiate a new char type array.
            this.topOfStack = -1; // we set the starting position of the topOfStack to -1.
        }
        // push method:
        public void push(char character) {
            if(isFull() == true) {
                System.out.println("Stack overflow error.");
            }
            else {
                topOfStack++;
                array[topOfStack] = character;
            }
        }
        // pop method:
        public char pop() {
            if(isEmpty() == true) {
                //System.out.println("Overflow.");
                return '\0';
            }
            else {
                char c = array[topOfStack];
                topOfStack--;
                return c;
            }

        }
        // top method:
        public int top() {
            if(isEmpty() == true) {
                System.out.println("The stack is empty.");
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                return array[topOfStack]; // returns the top element in the stack.
            }
        }
        // size method:
        public int size() {
            return topOfStack + 1;
        }

        // isEmpty method:
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            if(topOfStack == -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // isFull method:
        public boolean isFull() {
            if(topOfStack == array.length -1 ) {
                System.out.println("Stack if full.");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**BracketCheck.java**

```
 public class BracketCheck {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String text = "(())";
        //boolean check = isBalanced(text);

        if(isBalanced(text) == true) {
            System.out.println("Balanced.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not balanced");
        }
    }   
    public static boolean isBalanced(String text) {
        Stack stack = new Stack(25); // for simplicity our stack is going to be a size of 25.

        char[]arr = text.toCharArray(); // convert our string to a set of characters in an array.
        // here we are looping through our text
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i] == '{' || arr[i] == '(' || arr[i] == '[') {
                stack.push(arr[i]);
            }
            else if(arr[i] == '}' || arr[i] == ')' || arr[i] == ']') {
                if(stack.isEmpty()) {
                    return false; // if empty then return false.
                }
                else if((stack.pop() == '(' && arr[i] != ')') || (stack.pop() == '{' && arr[i] != '}') || (stack.pop() == '[' && arr[i] != ']')) {
                    return false; // here we return false because this tells us that there is a mismatch and not balanced. Also if we did pop out the brace and it was equal
                                  // to it's corresponding closing brace then it will just continue the loop other return false to indicate it is unbalanced.
                }
            }
        }
        if(stack.isEmpty()) {
            return true; // after looping through the text if the stack turns out to be empty then this shows that there the text is balanced indeed because
        }
        else {
            return false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this condition

```java
else if((stack.pop() == '(' && arr[i] != ')') || (stack.pop() == '{' && arr[i] != '}') || (stack.pop() == '[' && arr[i] != ']')) {
```

You pop 3 times, so you extract 3 different elements from your stack. To fix it, pop once and save popped element in local variable:

```java
if(stack.isEmpty()) {
    return false; // if empty then return false.
}
else {
    char element = stack.pop();
    if((element  == '(' && arr[i] != ')') || (element  == '{' && arr[i] != '}') || (element  == '[' && arr[i] != ']')) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ardenit! Works perfectly. I understand it now.